# encrypt the http request url on the local machine

Tags: python, qt, http, encryption, https

my software on the local machine needs to send http request to a specific web server , is there any way to protect the http request url from being found by Packet analyzer software like Wireshark and fiddler.
The sever is not mine, so I can do nothing in the server .

It would be better to show some code, I am an absolutely newbie in encryption .

P.S the  server  doesn't support https protocol

After some retinking on my question ,I found what I am really want is not let  any other guys using packet analyzer software know the server name (host name) my software is sending data to .

so I translate the host name to IP address format, it somewhat hide the host name.
Another question is : for common sites, is the IP address under the host name hardly  changing ?

Comment: If the server supports SSL, use that. But even using SSL will still show the server being called, since you will have to open a connection to this server before enabling SSL. Since the server will always require to decrypt your data, there is no way of having a one side encryption.

Comment: @SebastianLange the server doesn't support https protocol

Comment: Then you are out of options i guess. If you have access to the server-content (i.e. php/asp/...) you could have a encryption set up for decrypting the arguments, but the called URI will be visible in sniffers (though arguments are encrypted)

Comment: @SebastianLange I mainly want to hide  the called URI